# Highlight output path (decision tree) in d3 tree

Tags: d3.js, path, tree, highlight

Here i'm working on Decision tree using d3 tree example: [Search collapse tree](https://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950). In this example, user can search the node and the path from root to selected node will be highlighted. But in my case, when user enters, the nodes that connects to the output node, the path from the root node to the output node should be highlighted. Just like shown in the image:

[image]

I need to work the tree just like shown in the image but my logic seems not working. Please check out my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/qns0bet2/1/). To get the outputh path, i added a method named as "searchPath" that works on click function of "Find output path" button. (In fiddle, the click function is not working, dont know why. In normal html page it works):

```
function searchPath(){

    var searchText = $("#newpath").val();
    //alert(searchText)
    var textspl = searchText.split(",");
    var path="";

    for(var i=0;i<textspl.length;i++){
        var paths= searchTree(treejson2,textspl[i],[]);
        fullpath.push(paths[Object.keys(paths).length-1]);
    }

    console.log("finally : ");
    console.log(fullpath);


    d3.selectAll("circle").filter(function(d) { 

        console.log("circle name "+d.name);

    });

    //return fullpath;
}
```

To select the circle and link element based on the path, i added "id" attributes to those element. For circle, i give id as d.name and for link i give id as d.source.name+":"+d.target.name", so as to easily identify the source node and target node of a particular link.

But now i'm stuck with the code, i'm not getting any idea or logic to go forward.